# Applying functools.reduce to make Geopandas geometries valid for unary_union

Tags: python, geopandas, attributeerror, geodataframe

I want to calculate the total area of a GeoDataFrame, `year_df`, where the geometries overlap so I need to take the union. I was running into an issue with unary_union (some TopologyException that the input geometry is invalid) so I tried to get around this by applying `functools.reduce` to do the union step-by-step, making sure that each component was valid, like so:

```
union_poly = functools.reduce(lambda a, b: make_valid(gpd.overlay(a, b, how='union')), year_df)
```

However, this is unexpectedly giving me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

Any sense why Python thinks that each row of `year_df` is a string object? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

EDIT: the columns of `year_df` are:

```
Index(['ADM1_EN', 'ADM1_ZH', 'ADM1_PCODE', 'ADM0_EN', 'ADM0_ZH', 'ADM0_PCODE',
       'Entity ID', 'Acquisitio',  'acquisition_year', 'geometry'],
```

Comment: can you add your geodataframe columns to the question? Right now it unclear if you want to overlay two gdf or want to sum over. If only total area is required, calculate using `area` method and sum over. Also what is `year_df`?

Comment: Added. Total area will not work because the geometries overlap, so I need to take the union.

Comment: Have you tried [making it valid](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#validation.make_valid) then dissolve/unary union?

Comment: The individual geometries are valid. But trying to take the union creates something that is invalid for some reason -- which is what motivates the code example above.